# IPVS (keepalived) doesn't balance UDP connections

Tags: linux, rsyslog, udp, keepalived, lvs

I have two load balancer with Debian 8 and three Graylog server with Debian 9.

Every server in my network sends logs via rsyslog to a virtual server configured on the LB. The connection is UDP.

The problem is that the **packets are not balanced**. (all connections goes on the first real server on the list)

In case of failover the packets are correctly sent to the others real servers.

The only way I found to re-balance the connection is to remove all real server from the LB and the restart keepalived service.

I already tied to set:

```
ipvsadm --set 0 0 1
Timeout (tcp tcpfin udp): 900 120 1
```

I already set these two variables:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/expire_nodest_conn
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/expire_quiescent_template
```

IPVS is configure as follow:

```
vrrp_instance logserver {
    state MASTER
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 195
    priority 200
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type keepalived
        auth_pass xxxxxx
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        10.20.20.195/22
    }
}


virtual_server 10.20.20.195 0 {
    delay_loop 60
    protocol UDP
    lb_algo wrr
    lb_kind DR
    persistence_timeout 30

    real_server 10.20.20.196 0 {
        weight 100
        MISC_CHECK {
                connect_timeout 3
                misc_path "/etc/keepalived/checkgraylog 10.20.20.196"
        }
    }

    real_server 10.20.20.197 0 {
       weight 100
        MISC_CHECK {
                connect_timeout 3
                misc_path "/etc/keepalived/checkgraylog 10.20.20.197"
        }
    }

    real_server 10.20.20.198 0 {
       weight 100
        MISC_CHECK {
                connect_timeout 3
                misc_path "/etc/keepalived/checkgraylog 10.20.20.198"
        }    } }
```

Is there a way to effective balance UDP connection with Direct Routing?
Thank you

Comment: Sounds like this may be configured as a high availability cluster with failover.  Can you fail the first server and see if the logs start going to the second?  If so, it lends weight to what I've said.  I know nothing about IPVS so I can't give you an actual answer.

Comment: You're using weighted round robin but all the weights are equal? Just go with plain old round robin then. Or maybe least connections.

Answer (score 1):

```
virtual_server 10.20.20.195 12333 {
    delay_loop 60
    protocol UDP
    lb_algo wrr
    lb_kind DR
    ops # <<< - Try this. Works for me (Ubuntu 18.04, Keepalived v1.3.9, ipvsadm v1.28) 

    real_server 10.20.20.196 12333 {
```

Option `ops` for me works only if either:

- Virtual server port is explicitly defined.
- `fwmark` is used together with in virtual_server definition.

Does not work for `virtual_server_IP 0` form - in that case `ipvsadm -Ln` shows that `persistent` option is used as well.